# Ajax data function that should work but doesn't

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Within my application I have an Ajax function that adds information to a database. Everything worked perfectly until I added in 2 more parameters which was location and username.
It still works with everything else but it doesn't add those last 2 into the database. The names of within the database is location and username. assignedUsername and storeLocation are set else where in the code.

Ajax:

```
$("#send").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: orderFood(),
        url: rootURL + "/orderFood",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(assignedUsername);
            alert("Data Added");

            $.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu");
        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert(assignedUsername);
            alert("Data NOT Added");

            $.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu");
        }
    });
});

function orderFood()
{   
    alert(storeLocation + ", " + assignedUsername);
    return JSON.stringify({
            "food1": food1,
            "food2": food2,
            "food3": food3,
            "food4": food4,
            "food5": food5,
            "food6": food6,
            "food7": food7,
            "food8": food8,
            "food9": food9,
            "location": storeLocation,
            "username": assignedUsername
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
$app->post('/orderFood/', 'orderFood');

function orderFood()
{
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $q = json_decode($request->getBody());
    $sql = "INSERT INTO subsordered(food1, food2, food3, food4, food5, food6, food7, food8, food9, location, username) VALUES (:food1, :food2, :food3, :food4, :food5, :food6, :food7, :food8, :food9, :location, :username)";
    try
    {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam("food1",$q->food1);
        $stmt->bindParam("food2",$q->food2);
        $stmt->bindParam("food3",$q->food3);
        $stmt->bindParam("food4",$q->food4);
        $stmt->bindParam("food5",$q->food5);
        $stmt->bindParam("food6",$q->food6);
        $stmt->bindParam("food7",$q->food7);
        $stmt->bindParam("food8",$q->food8);
        $stmt->bindParam("food9",$q->food9);
        $stmt->bindParam("location",$q->location);
        $stmt->bindParam("username",$q->username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $db = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I know the PHP is correct though testing with cURL but I thought I'd include it just to get the whole picture

I am extremely stuck with this, from what I can see it SHOULD work but it just doesn't

Comment: Does it work if you manually enter a value to be added in the location and username fields? Like: `$stmt->bindParam("location","test location");`?

Comment: The PHP side of this works. No issues with that, it's just the Ajax that doesn't seem to want to work.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps I'm just confused, what do you mean the ajax aspect isn't working? Are those last two variables not being included in the json string? Are they not being sent to the PHP file?

Comment: what is your `console.log(orderFood());` ? and `console.log(data);`?

Comment: food1 - 9 inputs into the database with no issue but for some reason it doesn't input storeLocation or assignedUsername. As you can see there is no reason for it not to work and to even test out the variables I ran a couple alerts just to see if the variables were passing over, which they are.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers Due to issues with connectivity I am not able to test the application in a browser. I wish I could, it might make this much easier.

Comment: are `storeLocation` and `assignedUsername` always containing the expected values when `orderFood()` fires. It seems they are not local variables? are they promises? you are playing with AJAX which make things not always in sync.

Comment: They are hard coded globally. Also I was able to get it to run in a browser and it threw out OPTIONS http://localhost/sites/folderName/function 404 (Not Found) and an XMLHttpRequest error. Running it through a browser did not add in the information of any of the any food variables or location or username

Comment: I was a complete moron, I had 2 versions of the PHP code. I was editing the old version